# Difference between multiple rows in same column in SAS/PROC SQL

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I have a dataset temp1 as:

| ID | Drug | lob | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | acetam | counter | 01JAN22 04:25:17 |
| 123 | acetam | counter | 01JAN22 09:15:13 |
| 123 | acetam | prescr | 02JAN22 15:05:25 |
| 123 | acetam | counter | 03JAN22 23:28:05 |
| 234 | tylenol | counter | 11JAN22 18:12:39 |
| 345 | aztyr | counter | 03FEB22 16:11:19 |
| 345 | aztyr | counter | 03FEB22 16:15:20 |

- for the same ID, Drug, lob and the old timestamp create a flag as 'Yes'
- the second record of same ID, Drug, lob will also have a flag of 'Yes' when the timestamp is greater than 5 days compared to timestamp of previous entry.

expected output

| ID | Drug | lob | Timestamp | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | acetam | counter | 01JAN22 04:25:17 | Yes |
| 123 | acetam | counter | 01JAN22 09:15:13 | No |
| 123 | acetam | prescr | 02JAN22 15:05:25 | Yes |
| 123 | acetam | counter | 11JAN22 23:28:05 | Yes |
| 234 | tylenol | counter | 11JAN22 18:12:39 | Yes |
| 345 | aztyr | counter | 03FEB22 16:11:19 | Yes |
| 345 | aztyr | counter | 03FEB22 16:15:20 | No |

My Code:

```
create table temp2 as
select id, drug,lob, datepart(timestamp)as timestamp format=mmddyy10.
from temp1
order by id, drug,lob
quit;

data temp3;
set temp2;
by id, drug,lob
diff=timestamp-lag(timestamp);
if first.id and first.drug and first.lob  then do diff=.;end;
run;
```

I am first trying to calculate the difference between dates so that I can create a flag, but for the 3rd record for an lob='prescr' the diff I am getting is 1 but since the lob is different from the previous records this has to be considered as new record and flag has to 'yes'. I am stuck here and not able to move. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading up on BY group processing:
https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lrcon/n01a08zkzy5igbn173zjz82zsi1s.htm

Example 1 illustrates how the first. and last. variables are set.

If I understand correctly you probably want to do something like this

```
data temp3;
  set temp2;
  by id drug lob;
  diff = timestamp - lag(timestamp);
  if first.lob or diff > 5 then
    flag = 'yes';
  else
    flag = 'no';
run;
```